# Can anyone come up with an example of a monotonously not-falling function whose breakpoints are everywhere dense set on $[0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, functions, special-functions

$$f: \displaystyle{R\to[0,1]}$$

I can't come up with one, can anyone else ? :D

How about : $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x, x \in Q \\ 0, x\in I \end {cases}$$ ??

Comment: A [monotonous function](http://images.sodahead.com/polls/002486153/371809259_20080422_mindless_answer_1_xlarge.jpeg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

$$
f(x)=\sum_{y\in \Bbb{Q}, y\leq x} v_y,
$$

where the $v_y$ are positive with $\sum_{y\in \Bbb{Q}} v_y<\infty$?

Comment: Concretely, you can take $q_n$ to be an enumeration of the rationals and $f(x)=\sum_{n : x \leq q_n} 2^{-n}$.

Comment: Could you guys explain this more concretely? Im having trouble grasping it? What is $q_n$ more detailedly ?

Comment: @Jim Lowe: The set of rationals $\Bbb{Q}$ is countably infinite, so there is a bijective $p :\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{Q}$. Now set $q_n =p(n)$. It is also easy to see that every number in $[0,1]$ is a jump discontinuity of $f$. One could also show that no other discontinuities exist, but you do not need that for your claim.

Comment: Can you concretely define this bijective or they theory that it exist would be sufficient you would say if you were a professor?

Comment: @Jim Lowe: If at some point you already heard that the rationals are countable, then just stating that there is a bijective will be sufficient. For a few constructions (though mostly only f injections/surjections), see this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659302/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-the-rationals-is-a-countable-set