# prove: ℕ is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please, I need someone to help me to prove this theorem

- ℕ is countably infinite.

I know how can I prove it when the set define by something, but I'm confused and don't know how do this. 
Thanks

Comment: What's your definition of countably infinite? In general it's that a set $X$ is countably infinite if $|X|=|\Bbb N|$, in that case it's obvious...

Comment: What's your definition of countably infinite? Usually, the definition is that a set $X$ is countably infinite if there is a bijection $X \to \mathbb{N}$, which makes this proof fairly quick.

Comment: A set A is countably infinite (denumerable) ⇔ A~ℕ.

Comment: @alruwaytie: And presumably $A \sim \mathbb{N}$ means there is a bijection $A \to \mathbb{N}$? In which case... can you think of a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Take the identity function...

Comment: Since the question was originally tagged [tag:rational-numbers], are you sure you didn't mean to ask for a proof of "$\mathbb Q$ is countably infinite" instead? In that case, see for example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659302/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-the-rationals-is-a-countable-set) and the ones linked to it.

Comment: yes, it is for a prove of ℕ.

Answer (score 1):

One definition of a set $A$ being *countably infinite* is that we can find a function $f : A \to \Bbb N$ (where $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers) such that $f$ is a bijection, i.e., a one-to-one and onto map.  In other words, we can find a pairing between elements of $A$ and $\Bbb N$ such that each element of $\Bbb N$ is paired with a unique element of $A$, and each element of $A$ is paired with a unique element of $\Bbb N$.  This is called a "one-to-one correspondence".

Now, using the above definition, you want to show $\Bbb N$ is countably infinite, right?  So you need to find a function $f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ that is one-to-one and onto.  There is an obvious choice of function.  Can you think of what it is?  In other words, what should $f$ be?