# Is there an algorithm for the "zig-zag" proof that the rationals are countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms, proof-explanation

I'm sure that we've all seen diagrams such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pRJJ.png) to show how we can order sets such as the rationals in order to show that they are countable, however, is there a way to find the nth term of such a list? Can it be expressed as a formula? Or does this require some sort of algorithm?

Furthermore, can this be done without any informal appeal to "the nth line"?

Comment: It is a good idea to write down the algorithm in formulas, without picture. You should really try it. Do you know what $S_{ij}$ stands for?

Comment: Yeah, in this case it's i/j.

Comment: Highly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659302/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-the-rationals-is-a-countable-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) := \frac{x(x+1)}2 $$
$f(n)-f(n-1)=n$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$.
Also, $f(x)$ is one-to-one when $x \geq 0$.
The bijection you want is $$u_n=(n-f\left(\lfloor f^{-1}(n)\rfloor\right),f\left(\lfloor f^{-1}(n)\rfloor+1\right)-n-1) $$

Proof of surjectivity: Given $(a,b) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$, make $n=f(a+b)+a$. Then $u_n=(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the triangular numbering of the points of $\Bbb N^2$ as follows

each point $(i,j) $ with $i,j\ge 0$, will take the rank

$$r_{i,j}=\frac {1}{2}(i+j)(i+j+1)+j $$

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful.