# Generating the Sieve of Sundaram excluded index values

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, sieve-theory

I'm writing practice code, and I just did types oriented around generating `true`/`false` primality results (starting from 2, of course).  I did two types based on the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  On [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), I saw links to several other prime sieves.  Now I'm wanting to try out the [Sieve of Sundaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram).  I see the basic way to make the program, but I'm wondering how to generate the `i`/`j` forbidden indices.  Looking at the first few entries, in `i` then `j` order:

- (1, 1) → 4
- (1, 2) → 7
- (2, 2) → 12
- (1, 3) → 10
- (2, 3) → 17
- (3, 3) → 24
- (1, 4) → 13

I can't just loop on `j` then `i`, because that causes backtracking (for example: 12 to 10 and 24 to 13), and I'm going for streaming generation instead of a fixed `n`.  Right now, I'm thinking of keeping multiple `j` rows and extracting the smallest value each round, dumping a row once I exhaust it, and creating a new one every three rounds (at 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, etc.)

Then my research came across [this article](https://plus.maths.org/content/sundarams-sieve) from Plus Magazine.  It has a doubly-infinite array of arithmetic progressions that is the `i`/`j` chart.  The format looks like [the proof of rationals being countable grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2613969/216021), so I'm wondering if there's a snaking path through the `i`/`j` chart that will reach each number in order (eventually).

A simple snaking like the rational chart probably won't work, looking at the 10/13/16/17 intersections on the top and left.  I don't mind a snaking that hits equal or lesser values than the latest, as long as the next greater value is the immediately greater value.