# Why is the set $\mathcal B=\{\,\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\,\}$ countable?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I know that $\mathcal B=\{\,\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\,\}$ is a countable basis of $\mathbb R$ (for the Euclidean metric), but I don't really understand why it's countable. I tried to find a bijection between $\mathcal B$ and $\mathbb N$ but didn't work. Could someone explain?

Comment: Note, that $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Answer (score 4):

Each set $\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[$ is uncountable, but this is not of a concern: the set $\mathcal{B}$ *is* countable, because there is an injection
$$
f\colon\mathcal{B}\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}
\qquad
f(\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[)=(a,b)
$$
(because it is assumed $a<b$) and $\mathcal{B}$ is obviously infinite.

The set $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable (see [How to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ ( the rationals) is a countable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659302/62967)), so $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is countable as well.

Comment: I guess your answer and Surb one are the same. I really like your answer, but Surb answer is more visual for me (and thus more understandable), that's why I accepted his answer. But your answer is also a very good one (but unfortunately I can't accept both).

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal B=\bigcup_{\substack{(a,b)\in \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q\\ a\leq b}}\big\{(a,b)\big\}.$$

Comment: The right hand side is a set of ordered pairs, whereas $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of intervals.

Comment: @egreg: This is exactly the problem with english notation for the open interval $(a,b):=\{x\mid a<x<b\}$. I'm french, and I usually use $]a,b[$ for the open interval $\{x\mid a<x<b\}$. But since here people dislike this notation, I used the english notation that is very confusing in this situation... So what I was thinking is of course $\displaystyle\mathcal B=\bigcup_{\substack{(a,b)\in \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q\\ a\leq b}}\big\{]a,b[\big\}$ (using french notation)

Comment: @Surb: I'm from Belgium, and we also use $]a,b[$ for the open interval.

Comment: @Surb: But under the $\bigcup$, you use $(a,b)$ in a sense where it's a element of $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$, intervals aren't. - And for the record, I'm danish and use $]a,b[$ for open sets and find the notation with parentheses confusing and hard to read.

Comment: @Henrik: Indeed, and that's the problem (for me) with english notation for open interval...

Comment: Note: That's more an argument for why the notation with parentheses for open intervals is confusing than a critique of @Surb, I can't see how he could have done any better.